# TFS 2010 Build Service Executing Additional Tasks

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I need to execute an MSBuild process to perform some additional work after the build service has finished running.  Basically, after the app is finished, I need a process to move around the projects to new locations and do other transformations.  Is there a simple way to tell the TFS Build service to run additional tasks after the build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionRoot)\..\..\Build\Project\Installer.msi" DestinationFolder="$(BinariesRoot)\Destination" />
</Target>
```

You can use a different target if you prefer, ie "AfterDropBuild", whatever works best for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604.aspx

Comment: When you want to move the files on the builds folder (on the local drive of the build server), use the AfterCompile - which is executed on every solution build - or BeforeDropBuild - which is only executed once. If you want to move the files on the drop location (not recommended) use the AfterDropBuild